# Photoshop color picker giving me the incorrect color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I used the color picker tool to sample a color in one Photoshop document. The rgb returned was (1, 81, 144) - a shade of blue.

[image]

In a separate Photoshop document, I want to set the fill of a shape to my sampled color, so I click on the fill icon and go to the color picker. When I enter the rgb here, the color returned is not the same color. It's a shade of blue, but not the correct blue.

[image]

I've checked the color on w3schools color picker, and I'm clearly not getting the same color. I know I doing something, but can't figure it out. What am I missing here?

I'm on the latest CC version of Photoshop, Release 20.0.5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first document seems to 8 bit rgb while second seems to be 32 bit . there will be a lot of changes in color if you will change bit density of documents.

please make sure you created your new document with color mode RGB - 8 Bit :)

Figure 1 : color in RGB 8

[image]

Figure 2 :  Same color in RGB 32

[image]

Solution : while creating new document go to the Color Mode tab and if there is 32 bit change it to 8 bit and create new document and you should be fine to go with your desired color results :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: @MichaelvE Glad it resolved your issue :)